# jQuery Mobile: .animate({scrollTop}) doesn't work after fixing page transitions

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, scroll, jquery-animate, scrolltop

*jsFiddle links are at the bottom.*

I have a Phonegap app that I have created with jQuery Mobile. The page transitions were really choppy and inconsistent in the native iOS app until I found [this solution](http://outof.me/fixing-flickers-jumps-of-jquery-mobile-transitions-in-phonegap-apps/). It made my scrolling not so great, so I made a few changes per [this follow-up article](http://outof.me/native-scrolling-in-jquery-mobilephonegap-applications/).

After the first solution and still after I implemented the second solution, the following code stopped working for me in my app:

```js
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#specificID').offset().top}, 2500);
```

The above code scrolls the user down the page over 2.5 seconds to the DIV with the ID of `specificID`.

I have tried multiple things, but nothing seems to work:

```js
$('#container').animate({scrollTop: $('#specificID').offset().top}, 2500);
$('html, body, #container').animate({scrollTop: $('#specificID').offset().top}, 2500);
$('.scrollable').animate({scrollTop: $('#specificID').offset().top}, 2500);
$(".scrollable").animate({ scrollTop: $("#specificID").scrollTop() }, 2500);
```

So, here is how I adjusted my jquery mobile code to fix the page transitions:

**1. I wrapped `[data-role="page"]` DIV with `container` DIV**

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div data-role="page">
```

**2. I added the following Javascript**

```js
$(document).one('mobileinit', function () {  
  // Setting #container div as a jqm pageContainer
  $.mobile.pageContainer = $('#container');

  // Setting default page transition to slide
  $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'slide';
});
```

**3. I added the following CSS**

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
div#container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
div[data-role="header"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
div[data-role="content"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 41px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.scrollable {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
/* iOS specific fix, don't use it on Android devices */
 .scrollable > * {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
}
```

**I setup three jsFiddles to show this:**

1. Plain jQuery - scrollTop working: http://jsfiddle.net/pxJcD/1/
2. Transition Fix - scrollTop NOT working: http://jsfiddle.net/ytqke/3/
3. Transition Fix w/ Native Scrolling - scrollTop NOT working: http://jsfiddle.net/nrxMj/2/

The last jsFiddle is the solution that I am using and the one that I need to work. I provided the second one to show that the `scrollTop` functionality stopped before any of the native scrolling changes I made. **Any thoughts on what I can do to be able to scroll down the page using javascript?**

I’m using jQuery 1.8.2, jQuery Mobile 1.2.0, and Phonegap 2.2.0 (via Build).

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: Although I didn't go read your question deeply, I might add that a scroll animation works on document(ready), as long as the page is not cached. In other words you might need a unique uri so that jqm will reload the page.

Answer (score 2):

In your CSS, you have set your container's position property to Absolute.
Remove your `div#container`
It should work.

http://jsfiddle.net/nrxMj/16/

Comment: Thank you for your response. I see that it is working in the jsFiddle, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working that way inside the app. I know that it is hard to troubleshoot a native-app problem. Removing the `#container` CSS rules didn't create any problems with the page display or page transitions, but the scrollTop is still not working. I will study what you have proposed in more detail and see if there is something else I can do. In the meantime, if you or anyone else has any other thoughts - that would be great!

Comment: When I was building a Mobile site, I had the same problem with scrollTop, so I used $.mobile.silentScroll(position) instead. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/api/methods.html